# Need multiple language support in Ajax file upload

Tags: file-upload, jquery, internationalization, multilingual

I'm uploading a file using jQuery through Ajax. I'm submitting some form elements also, which needs to be [utf-8] multiple language support. When submitting, it becomes junk values. How do I solve this issue?

Help me. Thanks in advance.

Firefox am using.

```
 $.ajaxFileUpload(
        {
            url:action,
            workflow:workflow,
            arguments:argumentList,
            secureuri:false,
            fileElementId:filename,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data, status) {
                //alert(data);
                var id = $("#linkdata",data).find("label").html();
                var $htmldata = "<tr id='"+id+"'><td><label ><input id='' name=''  value='' type='checkbox'>Tenant</label>"
                            +"</td><td><label>"+title_e+"</label></td><td><label>"+title_a+"</label></td><td><label>"+desc_e+"</label></td>"
                            +"<td><label>"+desc_a+"</label></td><label class='fileuid '>"+file +"</label></td></tr>";
                            +"<input id='test' name='fileuidList'  value='"+id+"' type='hidden'>"
                //$("#fileuidList").val($("#fileuidList").val()+","+id) +
                $("#id_tenant").parent().append( $htmldata);
            },
            error: function (data, status, e)
            {
                alert("error"+e);
            }
        }
    )
```

the form is submitting as "multipart" if i remove that the value are coming correctly but file wont be coming. help me out

Comment: Could you please share a code sample? It's hard to guess what you are doing wrong (if anything). What web browser(s) have you tested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did a mistake with mysql configuration. now its working fine